# Difference between SqlConnection and SqlConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, connection

I would like to know what is different between `SqlConnection` and `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apples and Oranges.

`SqlConnection` actually controls the connection to the database.

`SqlConnectionStringBuilder` helps to dynamically create the connection string used in the `SqlConnection`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7):

`SqlConnectionStringBuilder` is simple a nifty utility to build/parse/modify a connection string. It's not esssential, and often it's entirely unnecessary.

`SqlConnection` is the actual database connection. You pass a connection string to it (doesn't matter if it came from a `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` or not) and you can talk to the database.